# convert qmake file to unix makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I have a cli program that I want to build on older machines (that don't have qt installed). My main development machine has QT and I use qt-creator to do most of my work, however when going to these older machines and running make, the makefile that is generated by qmake expects qmake to be available.

How do I make qmake files portable?
Edit:
platform is Linux, (various servers, some old some new)
using qmake to make a makefile doesn't work because the makefile created needs qmake (hence my question).

Comment: It depends... if you use the Qt libraries in your project (QString, QApp, QWidgets, etc), you will need to have Qt installed in order to compile your project.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `qmake` to make non Qt projects. It doesn't make any sense. However, if your project file is just a series of

```
SOURCES = ...
```

then just define a Makefile variable with the same values, define something like

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o, $(SOURCES))
```

And then define a rule like:

```
%.o: %.cc
      g++ -o $@ $<
```

(or whichever compiler is the right one).

You could also look at the generated Makefile, strip it down to its most basic expression, and drop the qmake file.

Comment: Well, it does make sense to use qmake to make non-Qt projects. It's a yet another meta-make tool - not as powerful as cmake, but of a similar kind. I'd avoid such absolute statements.

Comment: ...and it definitely makes more sense than writing makefiles by hand.

Comment: using qmake is the default in qt-creator which is my development platform of choice. I tried stripping the generated makefile to it's barest expression, but it got very complicated very fast. (It's a fairly large project).

Answer (score 1):

It would be helful, if you tell us your desire platform where you want to use make.

By using qmake, you can easily create Makefile for you desire platform, by running qmake as

```
$qmake -spec your_desire_platform_spec your_project.pro
```

Then run, make as

```
$make
```

Say, you want to run it on FreeBSD;

if you want to use clang, qmake as

```
$qmake -spec freebsd-clang your_project.pro
```

if you want to use g++, run qmake as

```
$qmake -spec freebsd-g++ your_project.pro
```

then run make

```
$make
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Nope this doesn't work because the makefile created expects qmake to be present. I'm looking for the stripped down simple make version. The environment is Linux on multiple servers.

Comment: You had my hopes up. I thought you had cleverly made a makefile that converts qmake files to make files.  The qmake file that I have in mind is quite large and covers multiple directories and conditional defines. I know I'll probably have to do it by hand, just hoping there was an auto method.